# Azure Media Service DRM

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

How can I get the authenticationToken for azure media player?

[image]

I tried but it's not working

Comment: Please don't paste code as an image.

Comment: Adding code or output as images, makes it impossible to search and for many users difficult or impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

See the following basic Streaming with DRM example for Typescript/Javascript SDK

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Streaming/StreamFilesWithDRMSample/index.ts
- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Streaming/StreamFileWithAESClearKey/index.ts